# Potential scattering for non-decaying potential

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, schrodinger-operators

I am reading [this note](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ezworski/tz1.pdf) on potential scattering by Siu-Hung Tang and Maciej Zworski.
Just wondering if there is a scattering theory for the Schrödinger with a non-decaying potential $- \Delta + V$ on the real line, like, for some $V$ that has an non-zero asymptote as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$.

Any reference/comment would be great - Thanks in advance!

Comment: A lot of what they did in those notes (the ODE and Wronskian analysis etc) can be reproduced when the potential has non-zero asymptotes. The specific case where $V$ is the step-function is also well-studied (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation_for_a_step_potential).

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks! I'll check it out